# Give different background color to OP in revision list

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, revisions-list, original-poster

Sometimes, the original poster of a question is making such edits: ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17528749/revisions))

> [image]

However, there is no easy way to tell this is the OP, hence that edit looks suspicious, and users might roll it back.

Can the background color please be different, to make it easier to see "this edit was made by OP"?

For example, white appears to look fine:

> [image]

Comment: Shouldn't the users that rollback such edits not simply be mod-messaged?  That is more helpful then spending time to implement something that isn't going to be noticed by the users that rollback useful edits....

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ umm... no? It's the same blue for all revision headers

Comment: @rene sure, why not nuke their account and put them in permanent IP ban?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ lol, silly me. Self slap. Etc. Post it as answer and I'll accept my shame. :-P

Comment: @ShadowWizard If I ever run for mod that will be my motto: IP bans for everyone and then we talk

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this feature request was completed even before Shadow asked it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A picture says a thousand words... :P

> [image: OP revisions have a blue header; edits by others have a gray header]

Comment: ++ MS Paint art

Comment: @Phrancis I've put that text as the image `alt` and the `title` -- hover over the image ;)